# Can I show two boxes in Magento Admin Grid Mass Action or select a date before action?

Tags: php, magento, datetime, datepicker, admin

I have created a Magento Admin Grid and am using Mass Action to set the start and stop dates.

Now my Mass Action runs as chosen in `dropdown list` select start or stop `datepicker` box will show after select first box.

Can I show two boxes at same time (`dropdown list` and `datepicker`) or `select date` before `dropdown list`?

My code:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('setstartdate', array(
    'label' => $this->__('Set Start Date'),
    'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSetstartdate', array('' => '')), 
    'confirm' => $this->__('Are you sure?'),
    'additional' => array(
        'setstartdate' => array(
            'name'   => 'setstartdate',
            'time'   => true,
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'type'   => 'datetime',
            'class'  => 'required-entry',
            'label'  => Mage::helper('setcustomdate')->__('Set start Date'),
            // 'gmtoffset' => true,
            'image'  => '/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss'
        )
    )
));

$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('setstopdate', array(
    'label' => $this->__('Set Stop Date'),
    'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSetstopdate', array('' => '')), 
    'confirm' => $this->__('Are you sure?'),
    'additional' => array(
        'setstopdate' => array(
            'name'   => 'setstopdate',
            'time'   => true,
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'type'   => 'datetime',
            'class'  => 'required-entry',
            'label'  => Mage::helper('setcustomdate')->__('Set Stop Date'),
            // 'gmtoffset' => true,
            'image'  => '/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss'
        )
    )
));
```

**Edit 1** update prepareColumns

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $helper = Mage::helper('setupdate'); 

    $this->addColumn('data_id', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Data No.'),
        'index'  => 'data_id'
    )); 

    $this->addColumn('startdate', array(
        'header'=> $helper->__('Start'),// store
        'index' => 'startdate',
        'filter_index' => 't1.start_date',
        'format' => 'F', 
        'type' => 'datetime', 
    ));

    $this->addColumn('stopdate', array(
        'header'=> $helper->__('Stop'),// store
        'index' => 'stopdate',
        'filter_index' => 't1.stop_date',
        'format' => 'F', 
        'type' => 'datetime', 
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Comment: show you prepare grid function

Comment: you mean '_prepareColumns' right? i update in question for you